# Why do ASP.NET API call freezes if is called as in official documentation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I was having trouble with making a POST query. I was using this method, strictly copied from the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client).

```
static async Task<Uri> CreateProductAsync(Product product)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/products", product);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    // return URI of the created resource.
    return response.Headers.Location;
}
```

But the application was freezing on the `.PostAsJsonAsync()` method.

I figured it out, since the method **actually isn't** an asynchronous method, the `await` was stopping the parent thread waiting forever.

So I thought it would be a nice try to remove the `await` and just extract the response with the parameter:

```
static async Task<Uri> CreateProductAsync(Product product)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/products", product).Result;
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    // return URI of the created resource.
    return response.Headers.Location;
}
```

And it worked. So, my question is: why the official documentation doesn't work for me? I guess I am doing something wrong... It works, but probably this is not the way.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**: this is my code:

Button click listener:

```
int statuscode = AsyncTaskLogin.RunAsync(data).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

RunAsync method:

```
public static async Task<int> RunAsync(LoginData login)
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    int responsecode = await CreateLoginAsync(login);
    return responsecode;
}
```

Create Login Async method:

```
public static async Task<int> CreateLoginAsync(LoginData login)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("posts/", login);
    //not reaching here unless i remove await tag and add .Response
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return (int) response.StatusCode;
}
```

Comment: *the method actually isn't an asynchronous method* Why not? Since when? It returns a task, so it is async.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I am Ctrl + left clicking the method and accessing the System.Net.Http class, where i can see the declaration and it doesn't have the async on it. I am new into C# so maybe I'm probably confused.

Comment: @CarlosLópezMarí this has signs of being an 
[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Where is `int statuscode = AsyncTaskLogin.RunAsync(data).GetAwaiter().GetResult();` run?

Comment: @Nkosi To me, it sounds like a normal deadlock issue of running `async Task`s synchronously in UI events

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto agreed. The cited documentation example from the OP is for a console application

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto from a button click listener

Comment: @CarlosLópezMarí show the code with the button click listener. Most likely you are mixing blocking calls with async calls and encountering a deadlock

Comment: Just use `async void ButtonClick` and `int statuscode = await ...` instead of `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

Comment: Labelling a method as async/await will save you from writting a lot of plumbing code in asynchronous methods. The compiler will handle it for you. But you can create asynchronous methods without using async/await. Plus I don't really know if you can tell if a method was compiled using async/await without seeing the source code.

Comment: Running async method from a non async one is a bad idea. You need to either async all the way from the start or none at all.

Comment: The official documentation assumes the client side code talks to an anonymous authenticated REST API, like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api Clearly yours talk to a third party web service so authentication and other criteria matter a lot.

Comment: FYI, the `async` is not part of the method signature. Control+click to go to definition will not show you the `async` modifier. The method is most certainly asynchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your main method is not async. Because of this, you were forced to call your asynchronous methods synchronously, and therefore also wait for them to complete synchronously. This results in a deadlock, as your main/ui thread is waiting for the async method to complete, but your async method expects the main/ui thread to pass it a SynchronizationContext - which of course, it can't actually do, because its blocked!

You have two solutions:

1. Async all the way. You turn your main method async and you await your asynchronous call as opposed to doing GetAwaiter().GetResult().
2. Use ConfigureAwait(false). You need to use it on every asynchronous call you make down the stack - not just one of them. So both CreateLoginAsync() and PostAsJsonAsync() need to have ConfigureAwait(false) tacked on after them. What this does is make it so that your asynchronous call doesn't ask for a SynchronizationContext when its about to callback, that way a deadlock is avoided.

The second point is considered a bad practice however because every single async call you make now has to have this piece of code tacked on - including libraries etc. Only do this if you absolutely cannot turn your main method async.

Comment: Nice, I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: First point wasn't posible as it was a button listener and I cannot async void. Sencond one worked, but some seconds (10 or 15) after getting the result, I still get the message of 'subprocess was killed with error 0'. I guess this is not a problem. Thank you for your answer.